# subtracting longs goes wrong

Tags: java, long-integer

```
long freeSize = ((Main.maxSPace-Main.usedSpace)*1000*1000);

maxSpace = 20000
usedSpace = 8
```

--> `freeSize = -1482836480`

Why is this the result negative?

Comment: Those are the values of maxSpace and usedSpace?

Comment: Do you declare maxSpace and usedSpace after the arithmetic or are you just telling us what they equal? You need to post more code

Comment: What type are variables maxSpace, usedSpace ?

Comment: You are probably getting long overflow. Let's see: `20000 - 8 = 19992` `19992 * 1000000 = 19992000000` oops, nevermind, that's less than `Long.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Are you sure `maxSpace` and `usedSpace` are in megabytes (which are 1024 bytes, not 1000), and not bytes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change type of `maxSpace` and `usedSpace` from `int` to `long`. If you can't do this then just change your code to something like

```
long freeSize = 1000L*1000*(Main.maxSPace - Main.usedSpace);
```

so result would be calculated as `long`, not `int`.

Now it is calculated like this

```
Main.maxSPace-Main.usedSpace              -> 19992
(Main.maxSPace-Main.usedSpace)*1000       -> 19992000
(Main.maxSPace-Main.usedSpace)*1000*1000L -> 19992000000
```

Problem here is that we are operating on integers, so result must also be integer, but max value of integer is

```
2147483647 so
19992000000 is out of range
```

so Java will take only last 32 bits of result and change it to integer

```
10010100111100111011011011000000000 -> 19992000000
   10100111100111011011011000000000 -> -1482836480
```

Answer (score 3):

`maxSpace` and `usedSpace` are declared as ints, so all the arithmetic is performed with ints. Only when you assign the result to `freeSize` is it cast to a long, but the overflow has happened before then.

Try replacing the number `1000` with `1000L` to cause the coercion to occur earlier:

```
long freeSize = ((Main.maxSPace-Main.usedSpace)*1000L*1000L);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting a negative number because `maxSpace` and `usedSpace` are ints. `20000 - 8 = 19992`, `19992 * 1000000 = 19992000000` which is less than `Long.MAX_VALUE` (2<sup>63</sup> - 1) but it is more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2<sup>31</sup> - 1). `19992000000 - Integer.MAX_VALUE = 17844516353` which is still out of bounds for the value of an int. You should let `maxSpace` and `usedSpace` be longs.

Answer (score 2):

When maxSpace and usedSpace are of type int you'll get a negative value because of type overflow. Use long instead for both variables maxSpace and usedSpace. Alternatively, if you can't change the property types of Main you can change your code to:

```
long freeSize = ((Main.maxSPace-Main.usedSpace)*1000L*1000L);
```